# Pronunciation of voiced "th" triggers a consonant shift of "d" and "r"

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

There is a class of words, mainly such as

> *the, this, that, these, those, though, although, then, there, thus,*
>
> the archaic *thou, thee, thy, thine, thyself, thence;*

which I always find myself pronouncing with a stopped sound intermediate between a  "d" and the smoother (fricative) sound of "th" in words such as

> *father, mother, brother, other, bother, rather, feather, dither, breathe, loathe, smooth.*

This seems fairly common in American English, but many people always pronounce a voiced "th" smoothly, and some think that speech that sounds too much like "dis, dat, deze, doze" is uneducated or not correct.  This pronunciation seems to push the "d" further back toward the "r", (for distinction's sake?) and the "r" even further back, deep against the soft palate.

I'm curious as to where and when this slight consonant shift has taken place in English, and where it is considered standard or not, as the case may be.

Comment: Can you link to a recording, or use IPA or standard terminology?  E.g., is voiced _th_ an affricate here?

Comment: I would say my stopped "th" is a voiced dental stop http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental_stop with the tip of the tongue at the inner gumline of the upper front teeth.  My smooth voiced "th" is a voiced dental fricative http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental_fricative with the tip of the tongue between the teeth.  (I have a hard time finding a consistent definition of the IPA symbols anyway.)

Comment: Just to be clear, my "d" is (to a small degree) retroflex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_stop and so is my "r" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_approximant -- I suppose "retroflex" is what I meant by "pushed back".

Comment: When you say _This pronunciation seems to push the “d” further back toward the “r”, (for distinction’s sake?) and the “r” even further back, deep against the soft palate_, do you mean this happens categorically (to every _d_, _r_) or only to those in the vicinity of /d̪/?

Comment: How does the position of your _d_ compare with that of your _t_?  Maybe best to avoid places where _t_ is aspirated when making the comparison.  Try _wagged_ versus _whacked_ (=_kt_), or _wisdom_ versus _system_.

Comment: Everybody has their own set of pronunciation habits. /ð/ can be pronounced practically any way and still be distinguishable because its occurrence can be predicted so easily; [d] or [dð] are common variants. This isn't a "consonant shift that has taken place in English"; this is a consonant shift that has taken place in **your** English. Perfectly normal; nothing to worry about.

Comment: Not just my English -- as you say, perfectly normal, just curious.

Comment: @DanielHarbour yes, categorically.  I say "d" and "t" in exactly the same position -- more retroflex at the end of a word than the beginning.  I noticed this pattern in my English when I learned Swedish.  My initial /d̪/ "th" sounds exactly like the Swedish "d" and my "d" sounds like a Swedish "r", except that it is only a single stop and not trilled.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure that there is a chain shift, though it is possible.  Ultimately, you would need to do careful measurements of *though*, *doe*, *roe* as said by:

1. members of your childhood cohort who pronounce *though* with [dð] not [ð],
2. members of your childhood cohort who pronounce *though* with [ð] not [dð],

I’m mildly doubtful of a chain shift because apico-dental and apico/lamino-coronal sounds can coexist in the same language, and, to make things easier, you have affrication help to differentiate voiced *th* from *d*.

That’s the best answer I can give on the available information!